# « Tous disponibles qu'ici vous aimez regarder » ?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Je suis tombée sur cette photo et j'aimerais bien savoir si cette formulation est correcte ou non.

> *Tous disponibles qu'ici vous aimez regarder*.

[image]

Comment: ça ne parait pas français du tout, je dirais plutôt une traduction mot à mot de quelque chose comme : "All available [that] you like to watch here"

Comment: @Archemar: It can't be a word-for-word translation from English; the word order of "everything available that here you like to watch" is almost as wrong in English as it is in French.

Comment: Je ne vois pas dans l'image, ça vient d'où ? Peut-être cette idée a subi plusieurs traductions.

Comment: @livresque c'est entouré en rouge, mais difficilement lisible en jaune sur gris.

Answer (score 3):

On pourrait penser que « que » est le pronom relatif, et alors il n'y a aucun antécédent puisque « disponible » est seulement un adjectif (seulement exceptionnellement un antécédent) et le pronom indéfini « tous » ne peut pas être un antécédent. Il n'est donc pas possible de considérer « que » en tant que relatif. Si on admet que « que » fait partie de la locution « ne … que » utilisé avec une ellipse de « ne », de sorte que « que » signifierait « seulement », la première partie (« disponibles qu'ici »), d'un style de langue familier, est correcte, mais la seconde (« vous aimez regarder ») communique une idée qui n'est connectée à celle de la première partie en aucune manière ; cette supposition ne résulte pas non plus en une phrase correcte. En conclusion, on doit dire que l'on ne sait pas ce que cela signifie en français, et plus pertinemment, que ce n'est pas du français correct.

En réfléchissant à ce que l'intention du rédacteur a pu être en écrivant cela on pourrait penser qu'il a cherché à exprimer l'idée suivante (une formulation en fait assez courante), mais il n'y a aucune certitude à ce sujet.

- Tout ce que vous aimez regarder disponible ici (*ellipse de la forme verbale : « Tout ce que vous aimez regarder **est** disponible ici. »*)

Answer (score 3):

LPH a remis la phrase d'aplomb. Je rajouterais qu'il faut comprendre dans ce contexte :

> **Toutes les chaînes que vous aimez regarder sont disponibles avec ce décodeur** (pirate).